# Stop Loop Property in wavesurfer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wavesurfer.js

I'm using **wavesurfer.js** in my new project. [(Source Link)](https://wavesurfer-js.org/)
It has some methods to use for backward/forward in the media player.
Methods : **skip(), skipBackward(), skipForward()**

The problem is when you are using **skip()**/**skipForward()** in last moments, before the media finish, it starts again from the beginning. I need to stop playing at the end. I don't want that loop property. I have searched the documentation. Nothing there also. It doesn't have a loop option to make it false!

Documentation Page : https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

*(Try it on localhost because of **CORS Policy: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin** error)*

```js
// WaveSurfer Create Method
var WaveSurferElement = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#wavesurfer',
    waveColor: '#000068',
    progressColor: '#9f5000',
    skipLength: 5,
    cursorWidth: 2,
    barWidth: 3,
    barRadius: 3,
    barGap: 3,
});

// WaveSurfer Load Method
WaveSurferElement.load('../files/example.mp3');

// WaveSurfer Ready Event
WaveSurferElement.on('ready', function () {
    // Enable Buttons
    $('#play-btn,#forward-btn,#backward-btn').prop('disabled', false);
});

// WaveSurfer Play Event
WaveSurferElement.on('play', function () {
    $('#play-btn').find('.icon').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
    $('#play-btn').attr('title', 'Pause');
    $('#play-btn').attr('id', 'pause-btn');
});

// WaveSurfer Pause Event
WaveSurferElement.on('pause', function () {
    $('#pause-btn').find('.icon').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
    $('#pause-btn').attr('title', 'Play');
    $('#pause-btn').attr('id', 'play-btn');
});

// Play Button Action
$(document).on('click', '#play-btn', function () {
    WaveSurferElement.play();
});

// Pause Button Action
$(document).on('click', '#pause-btn', function () {
    WaveSurferElement.pause();
});

// Forward Button Action
$(document).on('click', '#forward-btn', function () {
    WaveSurferElement.skipForward();
});

// Backward Button Action
$(document).on('click', '#backward-btn', function () {
    WaveSurferElement.skipBackward();
});
```

```css
body {
    direction: rtl;
}

.player-section {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #ff8100 50%, #000000 100%);
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.player-section .player {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 70%);
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.player-section .player,
.player-section .action {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000000;
}

.player-section .player .wavesurfer {
    margin-top: 90px;
}

.player-section .action {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}

.player-section .action .btn {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.player-section .action .btn.play-btn {
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.player-section .action .btn.forward-btn .icon {
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.player-section .action .btn.backward-btn .icon {
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.player-section .action .btn:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>WAVESURFER.JS</title>
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css">
        <!--/Styles -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="player-section">
            <div class="player">
                <div class="wavesurfer" id="wavesurfer"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="action">
                <button class="btn forward-btn" id="forward-btn" title="Forward" disabled>
                    <i class="icon fa-solid fa-forward-fast"></i><span>Forward</span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn play-btn" id="play-btn" title="Play" disabled>
                    <i class="icon fa-solid fa-play"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn backward-btn" id="backward-btn" title="Backward" disabled>
                    <span>Backward</span><i class="icon fa-solid fa-backward-fast"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/6.2.0/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
        <!--/Scripts -->
    </body>
</html>
```

As I said, the problem is when media is about to finish, Example:
[Wavesurfer On Playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57kgm.png)

And you click on **Forward Button**, It jumps to first of the media) Example: [Wavesurfer After Forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn6LC.png)

So in this situation, I wanna pause the media & keep the playing cursor at the end. (Or just stop it) I don't need the loop. What can I do ?!

Comment: Nobody any idea ?! :(